# How is this machine at 100% cpu when there is nothing high on the htop list?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, top, htop

I have a machine that is being slow and htop is telling me that the processor is locked at 100% but all the processes under it seem to be running pretty low CPU usage...

[image]

How is this possible? Shouldn't whatever is hogging the system show up there?

Comment: Howe many interrupts?

Comment: how can I see that?

Comment: It appears your list isn't sorted by CPU usage, so it's very likely that the culprit is off the bottom of the screen somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

From your image, it appears like you haven't sorted your current processes by percentage of CPU load.

If you are using htop, then press <kbd>F6</kbd> to change the default sort column. ([source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/using-htop-to-monitor-system-processes-on-linux/))

Alternatively, open a terminal window.
Type *top*

Similar to htop, the "top" application will ouput to your monitor the current processes running and updates every second. Hit the following key strokes at any time:

<kbd>M</kbd> Sorts by current resident memory usage

<kbd>T</kbd> - Sorts by total ( or cumulative) CPU usage

<kbd>P</kbd> - Sorts by current CPU usage (this is the default refresh)

<kbd>?</kbd> Displays a usage summary for all top commands ([source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=29588))

Comment: IDK why it appeared out of order there, but they were sorted by CPU usage and I even double checked it. Turns out there was a hardware problem on the physical machine. I got an email from amazon about it and I stopped and started and it cleared up